# how to override Custom theme phtml file by custom module

Tags: magento2, theme

I Want to override this is Current theme path that i want to override.
 I have a file In

> /public_html/app/design/frontend/Venustheme/fashion/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/gallery.phtml

but i want to override in my theme, Path Like :-

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/gallery.phtml

here is my xml file :-`preview_product_gallery.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>
            <referenceContainer name="content">
                <referenceBlock name="product.list.gallery">
                    <action method="setTemplate">
                        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::gallery.phtml</argument>
                    </action>
                </referenceBlock>
            </referenceContainer>
        </body>
    </page>
```

Comment: You can't extend your theme file into your custom module, since magento 2 use fallback method so initially it will look up the file in your theme then into your custom module i.e., app/code... So in order to override your theme file create a child theme by parenting your current theme . In such a way you can extend I hope

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example if you wants to overwrite the following file:

```
/var/www/html/magento2/app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<Theme>/</Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list/items.phtml
```

in to your module, then copy above file in following location and updated as you wants:

```
/var/www/html/magento2/app/code/<Vendor>/<Module>/view/frontend/templates/product/list/items.phtml
```

and add following code(just for example) in your module xml file:

```
<referenceBlock name="product.info.upsell" template="Vendor_Module::product/list/items.phtml"/>
```

Let me know if this is works for you.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you @kamlesh, but its not working. am trying different file path `/public_html/app/design/frontend/Venustheme/fashion/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/gallery.phtml`

Comment: Ok, this is your theme path. Now, may I know your module path?

Comment: I think your module path to overwrite this file should be /public_html/app/design/frontend/<vendor>/<module>/view/frontend/templates/product/view/gallery.phtml

Comment: thanks @kamleshyes, my module path is same as above..

Comment: still it not affecting

Comment: Are you extending class view from controller? I think you need to extend the class view from controller.

Answer (score 1):

If you two module one is Vendor_Module for layout and  Retailinsights_Preview for template file. then change code as belows in your preview_product_gallery.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <referenceBlock name="product.list.gallery">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Retailinsights_Preview::gallery.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
     </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

Comment: sorry for vendor/module mismatch i edited question, please checkout

Comment: Please let me know your preview_product_gallery.xml file path in module ?

Comment: Thank you for response. /public_html/app/code/vendor/module/view/frontend/layout

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code .

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <referenceBlock name="product.list.gallery">
                <action method="setTemplate">
                    <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Retailinsights_Preview::gallery.phtml</argument>
                </action>
            </referenceBlock>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can't overwrite a theme file with a module.

The best and cleanest way to handle this is creating you own theme that extends the one you are currently using and then overwriting the template.

This seems like it's a bit overkill at the beginning, but it has the benefit of your parent-theme to be updateable.